# When I add values to SQL via EF, ID is always 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

- I have an MVC project with connection to entity framework (db first).
- I have a class `User` that every time I try to add it to the db, it's `ID` is `0`.
- I tried to resolve it with adding property ID to the class, but couldn't get much progress either.

As far as I know, SQL should auto generate the Id's every time I add something, but it doesn't happen. What am I do wrong?

sql

```
create table Users
(
    ID bigint not null primary key,
    FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    BirthDate smalldatetime not null,
    Email varchar(50) not null,
    UserName nvarchar(50) not null,
    Password nvarchar(50) not null
)
```

c#

```
public class User
{
    //public long ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public User AddNewUser(Register signedUser)
{
   using (MyDBEntities context = new MyDBEntities())
   {
       User newRegisteredUser = new User {FirstName = signedUser.FirstName, LastName = signedUser.LastName, BirthDate = signedUser.BirthDate, Email = signedUser.Email, UserName = signedUser.UserName, Password = signedUser.Password };
       context.Users.Add(newRegisteredUser);
       context.SaveChanges();
       return newUser;
   }
}
```

Comment: What version of `Sql Server` you are using? Have you set the identity(1, 1) in the table column?

Comment: Is `Id` column configured as an identity column in sql server?

Comment: Is there a typo in your `AddNewUser` method? you seem to be adding `Users` and not `User` also, `newUser` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: You must be expecting a lot of users to make Id a `bigint`

Comment: @stuartd You can never dream to big. :)

Comment: @RandRandom allowing for every grain of sand on the planet to open an account - got to admire ambition..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Mark the primary key column `ID` in the table as [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) which will ensure that Sql Server will set the value of the column in each record.
2. Make sure that you also have the ID defined in your code on your Model and mark it as the primary key. Entity Framework (EF) needs to have a primary key so it can differentiate between records. This is important as soon as you start executing queries against the database using EF.
3. Mark the property with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` so that the value will not be sent to the database with an Insert AND the value added by Sql Server will be read back and applied to the model after the insert completes. You can do this with either attributes or fluent notation.

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    BirthDate smalldatetime not null,
    Email varchar(50) not null,
    UserName nvarchar(50) not null,
    Password nvarchar(50) not null
)
```

EF Model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Side notes

1. You could use `int` for your Id column unless you are designing a system that the whole world's population will use.*
2. It is hard to tell from your code but you might be persisting the user's chosen password in plain text. *If* this is the case you need to changing this code so that you store a secure hash of the chosen password (*use pbkdf2 or bcrypt or scrypt*). Never store the user's password as plain text or even using a reversible encryption algorithm, these are considered not secure.

Comment: Works perfect!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare it as an IDENTITY column like this:

```
create table Users (
ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key,
FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
BirthDate smalldatetime not null,
Email varchar(50) not null,
UserName nvarchar(50) not null,
Password nvarchar(50) not null
)
```